# Does the level I'm on affect the stats of the Giraffe on a Treadmill survival reward?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Is the Treadmill Giraffe you receive from beating level 25 on survival the same for all maps, or will I get a better one from playing on The Summit as opposed to The Deeper Well?

Comment: I believe so, but I haven't made a study of this so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rewards on the Summit are slightly better than rewards from the Deeper Well. However, the stats are so random and volatile that it makes little difference, especially on higher difficulties.

If you're wanting a pet that provides nothing but stats, I'd actually recommend a [Kobold on a Treadmill](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Kobold_on_Treadmill) or [Pet Rock](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Pet_Rock). They outclass the Giraffe in max stats, but is a bit more of a challenge to obtain them.

Comment: Note that the Kobold and Rock are also only available in DLC.